# Layout of QGroupBox

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, qt-designer, groupbox

I have made a gui (in Qt Designer) with a groupbox within another groupbox, and there are a few buttons, a progress bar and a label in it.

The label is over the progress bar, and it is selected in picture A. When I set the layout of "That groupbox" to "Lay Out in a Grid", I get what I want: the progress bar is resized when I resize the main window (picture B). As you can see, the problem is the label over the progress bar. How to set the layout so that the label is resized with the progress bar, like in picture C?

[image]